# Why is there no output in the console while accessing the database?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

This is the first time I'm using Eclipse and I was trying to create a connection to the database using Java. I did the procedure step by step and finally, when I clicked on run there was no output in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcconnection {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "password");
            Statement stm=con.createStatement();
            String sql="select * from student";
            ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3)+" "+rs.getInt(4));
            con.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);

        }

    }
}
```

My student table:

```
SQL> select * from student;

    STU_ID STU_NAME     BRANC       YEAR
---------- ------------ ----- ----------
         1 xyz          mech           2
         2 abc          cse            2
         3 efg          cse            2
```

Comment: Maybe your student table has no data, or you added data but didn't commit? Also, do not create your own objects in the `SYSTEM` schema, or any other built-in schema - create a new user and do all your work under that.

Comment: Posted the code as text and also added the image of my student table.

Comment: @AlexPoole  how can i check if the data is committed or not?

Comment: Try to query it from a different client or session; which is what you are doing from Eclipse. But if you've just inserted the rows in the SQL\*Plus session you showed you need to explicitly issue a `commit` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected; creating and populating a table as you've shown and running your code through Eclipse shows this in the console:

```
1 xyz mech 2
2 abc cs 2
3 efg cs 2
```

So, you appear to have inserted those three rows of data via SQL*Plus, but have not committed them. In Oracle data that has been inserted but not committed is not visible to any other session. The table itself is visible - because DDL like `create table` automatically commits, so you don't get an error. But the data in the table is not yet visible.

Just issue a `commit` in the SQL*Plus session after your insert statements (or exit, which commits by default), e.g.:

```
create table student (stu_id number, stu_name varchar2(10), branch varchar2(5), year number);

insert into student (stu_id, stu_name, branch, year) values (1, 'xyz', 'mech', 2);
insert into student (stu_id, stu_name, branch, year)values (2, 'abc', 'cs', 2);
insert into student (stu_id, stu_name, branch, year)values (3, 'efg', 'cs', 2);

commit;
```

After you commit your Eclipse session will be able to see the data.

Comment: thanks, it worked also how can i create my own user in oracle?

Comment: [Administering User Accounts and Security](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admqs/administering-user-accounts-and-security.html).